# How does this lambda get its function argument in common lisp?

Tags: lambda, arguments, common-lisp, sbcl, function-call

I have a table list:

```lisp
(defvar moo '((:name "vince" :age 35)
              (:name "jess" :age 30)))
```

and I call this function on that list:

```lisp
(defun test (name)
  (remove-if-not
   #'(lambda (person) (equal (getf person :name) name))
   moo))

(test "vince") ;; function call
;; => ((:name "vince" :age 35))
```

In the lambda function, how does the `(person)` parameter get filled? `person` is also used in the `getf` but I'm not sure how it's being discovered in the first place if I am only supplying the `name` in the test function.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLHS for
[*Function* ... `REMOVE-IF-NOT` ...](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) says:

> **remove-if-not** *test sequence &key from-end start end count key => result-sequence*
> ...
> ...
> **remove-if-not** return[s] a *sequence* from which the elements that *satisfy the test* have been removed.

And further [it says](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_s.htm#satisfy_the_test) (paraphrasing):

> **satisfy the test:**  for an element `el` of `seq` in the call `(remove-if-not test seq :key key)`, whenever `(test (key el))` returns *true*.

Furthermore,

```
[10]> (remove-if-not #'(lambda(x)(= 2 x)) '( (1) (2 2) (3 3 3)) :key #'length)
((2 2))
[11]> (remove-if-not #'(lambda(x)(/= 2 x)) '( (1) (2 2) (3 3 3)) :key #'length)
((1) (3 3 3))
[12]> (defvar qq '( (1) (2 2) (3 3 3)))
QQ
[13]> (remove-if-not #'(lambda(x)(/= 2 x)) qq :key #'length)
((1) (3 3 3))
[14]> qq
((1) (2 2) (3 3 3))
[15]> (eq qq (remove-if-not #'(lambda(x)(/= 2 x)) qq :key #'length))
NIL
[16]> (eq qq (remove-if-not #'(lambda(x)(/= 22 x)) qq :key #'length))
T
[17]>
```

So we don't really need to see the actual source code to find out what it does.

So the `test` lambda function gets called for each element in the sequence, for instance

```
(funcall #'(lambda(x)(/= 2 x)) (length '(1)))
=
((lambda (x) (/= 2 x)) (length '(1)))
=
(let    ((x            (length '(1))))
             (/= 2 x))
=
T
```

That's how function calls are made -- the lambda function's parameter gets the value of the argument in the function call, and then the lambda function's body gets evaluated under this binding.

Answer (score 1):

It's filled in my `remove-if-not`. It contains a loop that calls your function, passing the current element of the list as the argument.

Ignoring all the options that `remove-if-not` takes, it's essentially:

```
(defun remove-if-not (func list)
  (loop for item in list
        if (not (funcall func item))
        collect item))
```

Your lambda gets the argument from `(funcall func item)`

Comment: wow... i didnt get that from the clhs when i read it. I am curious, with elisp it's pretty easy to read the function I want to learn about. How can I go deeper that (documentation...) and read the whole function/macro for CL functions?

Comment: There are open-source Common Lisp implementations. See https://common-lisp.net/implementations for a list.

Comment: I understand. Using SBCL as an example, where can I read the `remove-if-not` function source code? I cannot find it on github either.

Comment: Usually i install sbcl from source, compile it with "./make.sh --fancy", and when doing so I'm sure all the source code is accessible by pressing meta-dot (M-.) in emacs/swank

Comment: https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/d35ad6f9bee212499cb827fec3195bf2064c10a2/src/pcl/sequence.lisp#L1035